# PowerShell 6.1.3 doesn't recognize any PackageManagement cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-v6.0

I've installed PowerShell 6.1.3 and I try to run some commands e.g.:

```
Get-PackageProvider
```

or

```
GetPackage
```

and then I get the following errors:

```
Get-PackageProvider : Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for
'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an
exception.'
Name:'TypeInitializationException'
Stack Trace:'
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageProvider.ProcessRecordAsync()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<AsyncRun>b__0()'
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PackageProvider
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:GetPackageProvider) [Get-PackageProvider], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnhandledException,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageProvider
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Probably by [installing the modules](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/02/update-powershellget-and-packagemanagement/)

Comment: When I run Update-Module, I get the same error(

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this error? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue, running the Nuget related commands threw the exception. But, then I ran the similar commands in "Powershell in Admin mode" and I could resolve the problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.